# Taking limit and $\sup$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was reading a proof for $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is complete. One of the steps is that given
$$||x_m - x_n||_\infty = \sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} | {x_m}_i - {x_n}_i| \leq \epsilon,$$
then for each $I\in \mathbb{N}$
we have 
$$\sup_{1\leq i \leq I}| {x_m}_i - {x_n}_i| \leq \epsilon.$$
Keeping $I$ and $n$ fixed and letting $m\rightarrow \infty$, we obtain 
$$\sup_{1\leq i \leq I}| {a}_i - {x_n}_i| \leq \epsilon.$$
Since $I$ is arbitrary, we conclude that 
$$\sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} | {a}_i - {x_n}_i| = ||a-x_n||_\infty \leq \epsilon.$$

My question is about the importance of introducing the $I$. 
From the definition of limit, I can see that when we take the large $M \in \mathbb{N}$, it depends on $i$, so for the argument's sake, we would like to fix $1\leq i \leq I$ at first. Now in general, when could we justifying switching the order between limit and $\sup$ 
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} | {x_m}_i - {x_n}_i| = \sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} | {a}_i - {x_n}_i| \;?$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's this $x_i$ and $x_{mi}$! why $x_{mi}\to x_i$?

Comment: @Hamou Given $x_n \in l^\infty$ is cauchy, each component ${x_n}_i$ is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, so we have ${x_n}_i \rightarrow x_i$ for some $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$. We can then define $x = (x_1, x_2,...)$

Comment: By your notation   $x_i\in \ell^{\infty}$ not in $\mathbb{R}$. If there is no problem for the notation why the sequence $(x_{ni})_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @Hamou Let me use $a_i$ instead of $x_i$, it was a bad notation I guess. For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n,m \geq N$ we have $|{x_n}_i - {x_m}_i| \leq ||x_n - x_m||_\infty \leq \epsilon$. So ${x_n}_i$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R} and we say it converges to $a_i$.